# Center align content of a col

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am trying to align the latin text in this example below to be vertically center. Right now, it aligns to the top of the yellow col.

[CLICK TO SEE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMoNP.png)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row g-5 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
              <div class="row">
              
              
              
                <div class="col-sm-6 justify-content-center" style="background-color:yellow;">
            
                    <h2>Heading Here</h2><br>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
                      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:pink;">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="img2.png"
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried some suggestions here but they don't work inside the context of the yellow and pink cols that are made to display side-by-side horizontally on desktop, but stack vertically on pink. It is important that such behavior remains.

Adding in d-flex align-items-center to the yellow div works sorta but it but the H2 left of the latin text, instead of above it. So there's gotta be another way...

Answer (score 0):

Try `flex-wrap`

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 d-flex flex-wrap" style="background-color:yellow;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you can add `d-flex f-column` to the yellow col in order for `justify-content-center` to work properly.

```css
/* simply to higher the .row */
.the-row {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row g-5 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="row the-row">
        
        <div class="col-sm-6 justify-content-center d-flex flex-column" style="background-color:yellow;">
          <h2>Heading Here</h2><br>
          
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:pink;">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img2.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```